# Finding the number of files in a folder

Tags: files, find, variable

How can I find a number of files in a folder, assign it to a variable, then echo that variable, all in one command line?

Comment: Do you want to include sub-directories in this count?

Comment: @Dave    yes including subdirectories

Comment: Any type of file? Or just regular files? Excluding directories? What about symlinks (to regular files or others). What about files (hard-)linked several times (or in other words, do you want to count files or directory entries)? What about the `.` and `..` entries? Do you want them included?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  jus regular files within a parent directory and its subfolders .

Answer (score 2):

```
linecount=$(find /folder/name/here/ -type f | wc -l); echo ${linecount}
```

is the simplest way of doing this. it counts every file in the folder and its sub-folders.

Comment: This isn't correct in the presence of files or directories with carriage returns in their filenames.

Comment: @pericynthion, carriage return wouldn't be a problem, linefeed aka newline would though.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my head without using `semicolon` to break and start a new command is to use [Parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) with [Command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)

```
$ echo ${filecount=$(find . -type f | wc -l)}
```

Then you can `echo` the variable again and you can confirm the result.